# How does the energy travel through the particles in a transverse wave?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, waves

I can see that the particles are displaced perpendicularly but how is the energy actually moving through these particles? I mean the first particle is moving up and down, and then the second should also move up and down by less than or equal to. But it is actually moving higher than the previous one when we draw a curve representing the wave. Is energy not used by the first particle? How does the energy transfer take place?